# search in jquery mobile returns blank page

Tags: jquery, search, mobile

Regular prelude: new to jquery mobile, sorry for the long pieces of code.

Trying to build a mobile version of my theme.
started easy by placing a header content and panel and search form.

when searching for something I do see in the network log that the request was successfully made, correct data returned and the url changed accordingly to the search param :
mysite.php/?s=wordpress
BUT the page is now blank and in inspect elements nothing except header (no scripts no body)
and I checked in the "network tab" and "console" tab for errors - nothing to be found.

header page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="demo-page" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" style="display:none;">

        <div class="fixed-header">
            <div class="cell">
                <div onclick="closePost()">
                    <div class="power <?php echo is_single() ? 'close':'open' ?>"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url');?>"  data-ajax="false">
                    <img class="logo" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/images/logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <a href="#right-panel" data-theme="d" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc"><img class="menu" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/images/menu.png"></a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <dl id="dlContent">
```

index.php:
    `<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>`

footer:

`

```
    </dl>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="c" style="position:fixed;">
    <p>SIDEBAR</p>

    <form action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="search" name="s" id="search" value="" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right">Close</a>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

`

Answer (score 0):

No comments but ill answer anyway for future clueless jqm developers as me.
apparently (wasent clear for me base on my regular web dev experience) that if the destination is not a jquery mobile page it wont load and show blank...
weird? or maybe there is other explanation that i didn't noticed while deleting and rebuilding the code.